# an error occurred on the server. printing will be stopped crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports-2008

I am using crystal reports 2008.

The report gets binded in the crystal reports viewer, but while printing the report I get the following error in alert box "an error occurred on the server. printing will be stopped"twice and its not printing or showing the print dialog box.

When looking through the event log, the below error was triggered,

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0
Date:          1/12/2013 2:03:55 PM`enter code here`
Event ID:      1309
Task Category: Web Event
Level:         Warning
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      ComputerName
Description:
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 12/01/2013 02:03:55 م 
Event time (UTC): 12/01/2013 10:03:55 ص 
Event ID: 6d36a824679b43b192e1897e91673936 
Event sequence: 82 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/7/ROOT-4-130024585909318740 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\Projects\Sample\ 
    Machine name: ComputerName

Process information: 
    Process ID: 2264 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: IIS APPPOOL\ SampleVssSrc 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: FileNotFoundException 
    Exception message: Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.Web.resources, Version=12.0.2000.0, Culture=ar, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 

Request information: 
    Request URL: //localhost:90/Sample/ Sample.aspx?ReportFileName= Sample.rpt&ReportPath=../Reports/General/../ Sample /Sample ReportViewer.aspx?ReportFileName =Sample Daily.rpt&ReportPath=../Reports/General/&ServletTask=Print&cmd=get_res&langcode=ar 
    Request path: /Reports/ Sample ReportViewer.aspx 
    User host address: ::1 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\ SampleVssSrc

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 6 
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\ SampleVssSrc
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalGetSatelliteAssembly(CultureInfo culture, Version version, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound)
   at CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalReportViewer.OnPrintGetResource()
   at CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalReportViewer.HandlePrint()
   at CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalReportViewer.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by disposing the Report Document object in the Page_Unload event, Make sure the Report document object is globally declared. This happens due to the temp folder memory, the temporary report files gets on created, but not disposed.